# Laravel mix unable to resolve aliased files from webpack.config.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, webpack, laravel-mix

I've been trying to fix this for the last 2hrs now. 
The thing, is I have upgraded to laravel 5.8 from 5.7. I had defined an alias

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
       "~": path.resolve(__dirname, "resources/js"),
    }
}
```

but now, after the upgrade, laravel mix can't resolve any of the files with this alias.

I am using phpstorm idea though, I have linked webpack.config.js with phpstorm and works just file but this is not compiling with laravel mix.

I have:

- removed node-modules and reinstalled again
- removed package-lock.json
- npm cache --clear --force
- installed yarn tried with it nothing
- installed babel-loader and vue-loaders nothing still
- had installed some eslint-import-resolver-alias

Done all the above and still gets the error: 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually found my issue: I hadn't somehow, I had deleted the import on `webpack.config.js` in `webpack.mix.js`